# hiding and showing divs in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a menu and when I click on a tab I want to hide whatever is currently displayed in my viewer and show the content corresponding to the tab I clicked on, (for all tabs).

```
<div id="main_view">
    <ul>
        <li id="tab_1">tab 1 </li>
        <li id="tab_2">tab 2 </li>
        <li id="tab_3">tab 3 </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab_1_content"> </div>
    <div id="tab_2_content"> </div>
    <div id="tab_3_content"> </div>
</div>
```

but I do not wish to do something like,

```
//tab, 2 and 3 content starts as hidden:
$('#tab_2_content').hide();
$('#tab_3_content').hide();

$('#tab_2').click(function, () {
    $('#tab_2_content').show();
    $('#tab_1_content').hide();
    $('#tab_3_content').hide();
});
```

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: You're not using the jQuery UI tabs widget are you?

Comment: No i'm using a different custom menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('li[id^="tab_"]').click(function(){
    $('div[id^="tab_"]').hide();
    $('#' + this.id + '_content').show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/N7whh/1/).

Or:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('ul').nextAll('div').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/N7whh/2/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: Nice, did not know about nextAll. also like how you did the `ul ~ div.hide()` very nifty. Thanks

Comment: And if you want to show the first `div`, rather than hide *all* of them, you can use, instead: [`$('ul + div ~ div')`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/N7whh/3/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Give your tabs a class

```
<div id="tab_1 tab">
```

Then you can do $("li.tab").hide() and it will hide all tabs with the tab class. Then:

```
$($(this).attr("id") + "_content").show();
```

Well, you get the idea. Just fill in the blanks.

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` gives exactly the same property as `this.id`. Which do you think is more efficient?